# fs.readFileSync not working in node.js create server

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node.js-fs

I know that this question is many.But mine is a little hard. I'm new to fs and i wanna read a file from txt and send it to client when it gives me a `GET` request and when it gives me a `POST` request. Sending the request is completly fine as i checked and its using XMLHttpRequest.First of all here is my code :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log("Recieved request : " + req.method);
  fs.readFileSync("chat.txt",(err,data) => {
    console.log("hello");
    if(req.body){
        console.log("Received message : " + req.body);
        var chats = data.split("\n");
        if(chats.length == 40){
            chats.shift();
        }
        chats.push(req.body);
        var results = "";
        for(var i in chats){
            if(i == chats.length - 1){
                results += chats[i];
            }
            else{
                results += chats[i] + "\n";
            }
        }
        fs.writeFileSync("chats.txt",results);
    }
    else{
        console.log(data);
        res.end(data.toString("utf8"));
    }
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

I think the problem is from the Sync and Async of readFile and writeFile and beside this problem, Can you say what is `async` `await` and `promises` very summarized and simple?

Comment: the things in readfileSync doesnt run...Like `console.log("hello")`

Comment: `readFileSync()` doesn't take a callback function, the file content is the return value.

Comment: The callback function is used with `readFile()`, not `readFileSync()`.

Comment: why its used with readFile and not used in readFileSync?

Comment: Since it's synchronous, there's no need to use a callback, it would just make it more complicated.

Comment: can you define synchronous and asynchronous in an answer?

Comment: Asynchronous functions return immediately, before the operation completes. They either return a promise or take a callback function that will be executed when the operation completes.

Comment: That's JavaScript basics.

Comment: I searched many documentaries about this but your answer was very good

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-javascript/

Comment: Just a heads up, if your making a HTTP server then you defiantly want to use `readFile` and NOT `readFileSync` unless `readFileSync` was used in a worker.  If you can also learn about `async / await`, you could then use `fs/promises` and that will make your code much easier to understand.

Comment: Note that you're not doing ANY validation of what's in `req.body`.  A rogue client could literally send you anything.  You cannot trust what is in there.  You must verify it's contents seem appropriate before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js' `fs.readFileSync` and `fs.writeFileSync` are not accepting callbacks - they are **synchronous**. Instead, they return the relevant value and throw errors.

You also need to specify the encoding in `fs.readFileSync()` to make it return a string.

Your code should look something like this:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log("Recieved request : " + req.method);
  // Read the file as text with UTF8 encoding and save the read data to a variable
  let data;
  try {
    data = fs.readFileSync("chat.txt", 'utf8');
  } catch(err) {
    // When an error occurs while reading the file
    // Do something with the error and return
    // because we have no data
    return;
  }
  console.log("hello");
  if(req.body){
    console.log("Received message : " + req.body);
    var chats = data.split("\n");
    if(chats.length == 40){
      chats.shift();
    }
    chats.push(req.body);
    var results = "";
    for(var i in chats){
      if(i == chats.length - 1){
        results += chats[i];
      } else {
        results += chats[i] + "\n";
      }
    }
    try {
      fs.writeFileSync("chats.txt", results);
    } catch(err) {
      // If an error occurs while saving the file
      // Catch it here and do something
      return;
    }
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    res.end(data.toString("utf8"));
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

**EDIT:** Added `try/catch` statements to catch errors while reading/writing the file.

Comment: You are missing `try/catch` to catch errors on `fs.readFileSync()` and `fs.writeFileSync()`.

Comment: I'm glad you added `try/catch`, but it might have been better with one try/catch around the whole block of code because there are other places this code could throw and you probably don't need two separate try/catch  blocks.  Also, the key aspect of handling an error in a request handler is you MUST send a response to the incoming http request (probably a 500 response if it's an unknown or unexpected error).